# Find Xcode Derived Data Location From Shell

Tags: xcode, xcode10

In Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Derived Data, you can specify a location for your derived data location.

I'm building a script and I'd like to be able to infer this location from the command line. I don't see anything in the Xcode app files.

Is there any way to read the current settings of Xcode from the terminal? It isn't a sensitive operation and doesn't need to be perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the information  of the build are in the project file.

You can get all build settings with:

```
xcodebuild -project yourapp.xcodeproj -showBuildSettings
```

then you can use a grep to get the build dir:

```
xcodebuild -project projectname -target targetname -showBuildSettings | grep -m 1 "CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR"
```